# Homogeneous coordinate ring of finite set in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-space

I want to show that the homogeneous coordinate ring of a finite set in projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

If I can show that this is regular ring then it is done. But I cannot prove that this ring is regular.

Help me. Thanks.

Comment: The homogeneous coordinate ring of a finite set in projective space is one-dimensional and reduced hence Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: Why this is reduced ring ?

Comment: The ideal of a finite set of points in $\mathbb P^n$ is a finite intersection of prime ideals, hence radical.

Comment: alright..i understand..thanks